# Convert a pandas dataframe column from float to object, with mixed float and int values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe with mixed value types. Some a true decimal types, others are true integer types. I am institutionally constrained to display the integer types without a .0 decimal. I want to convert this column to object type with some rows as float64 and some as int.

My current attempt is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'A': [7.62, 5.0, 10.25, 3.0, 8.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['A'] = df['A'].astype('object')

# Function to format the values 
def format_decimal(x):
    if x % 1 == 0:
        return int(x)
    else:
        return x


df['A'] = df['A'].apply(format_decimal)


print(df)
```

| A |
| --- |
| 7.62 |
| 5.00 |
| 10.25 |
| 3.00 |
| 8.00 |

This fails to return the column with 5 rather than 5.0. If necessary, it would be alright to have the integers represented as strings, I just need to drop the .0 characters.

Comment: You cannot have a Pandas column with mixed float and int values; as you have seen the dtype will revert to float.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I was mistakenly using `strip`. My edited solution will work if your original column has floats (5.0 will have one trailing 0 when converted to string, for example), but the solution proposed by @mozway is more robust.

You can convert column to string and replace the trailing `.0`:

```
df["A"] = df["A"].astype("string")
df["A"] = df["A"].str.replace(r".0$", "", regex=True)
```

```
       A
0   7.62
1      5
2  10.25
3      3
4      8
```

Comment: That will unfortunately fail on numbers like `10` or `100.00`.

Comment: @mozway True. I was mistaken about how `strip` works.

Comment: FYI, if you have a fixed substring, `'10.0'.removesuffix('.0')` does that. I was added fairly recently (python 3.9), I guess since many misused `strip` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep numbers, then create an object Series:

```
def try_cast_int(s):
    return pd.Series([i if (i:=int(x))==x else x for x in s],
                     dtype=object, index=s.index)

df['out'] = try_cast_int(df['A'])
```

"*If necessary, it would be alright to have the integers represented as strings, I just need to drop the .0 characters.*"

The convert to string and use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the trailing `.0`s:

```
df['out'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.replace('.0*$', '', regex=True)
```

Example:

```
         A     out
0    7.620    7.62
1    5.000       5
2   10.250   10.25
3    3.000       3
4    8.000       8
5  100.000     100
6   10.001  10.001
```

*NB. the first code creates an object Series with mixed int/float, the second creates strings.*

Used input:

```
data = {'A': [7.62, 5.0, 10.25, 3.0, 8.0, 100.0, 10.001]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `apply()` and a lambda function to conditionally format the values like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [7.62, 5.0, 10.25, 3.0, 8.0, 100.0, 10.001]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def format_decimal(x):
    if x == int(x):
        return str(int(x))
    else:
        return str(x)

df['out'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: format_decimal(x))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         A     out
0    7.620    7.62
1    5.000       5
2   10.250   10.25
3    3.000       3
4    8.000       8
5  100.000     100
6   10.001  10.001
```